# How do I change the language of the checkout form in Stripe?

Tags: api, localization, stripe-payments, locale, checkout

I have noticed that with the Stripe checkout form, the language seems to be fixed in English.

Is there a way for me to change this language to, for example, Spanish, Japanese or Chinese?

I'm currently using the default form code on the Stripe documentation:

```
<form action="/charge" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_variable_here"
    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-name="My Company Pty Ltd"
    data-description="2 widgets"
    data-currency="aud"
    data-amount="2000">
  </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: *Updating the answer since it's the accepted one to make sure it's visible.*

Stripe [released](https://stripe.com/blog/checkout-in-more-languages) a feature that allows you to have Stripe Checkout display in other languages automatically.

The easiest solution is to pass `data-locale="auto"`to display Checkout in the user's preferred language, if [available](https://support.stripe.com/questions/what-languages-does-stripe-checkout-support). English will be used by default. You can also force a specific locale in `data-locale` as long as it's one officially supported by Stripe.

Comment: It should be noted that this does not change the label of the pay button that still says "Pay with Card".

Answer (score 5):

Late answer but I think it can help someone.
Add line: `data-locale: "language"` to your script.
Example:

```
<form action="/charge" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_variable_here"
    data-locale="fr"
    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-name="My Company Pty Ltd"
    data-description="2 widgets"
    data-currency="aud"
    data-amount="2000">
  </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Stripe released a [new version of Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) last year which does language localization automatically based on the browser's locale setting. You can also manually override this behavior by [passing in a locale](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-locale) when creating a Checkout Session.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**"locale" parameter**](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-locale) to change the language of the checkout on **Stripe**.